# "ImportError: No module named readline" running "repo init"

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, readline

I downloaded the source of Android, but when I used `repo init` according to [the website](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bin/repo", line 91, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: No module named readline
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and Python 2.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the default Python environment in Ubuntu 10.04 is Python 2.6.5, so you must be using a self-compiled python.

You should be missing some readline header files when building your python 2.7.2, so you have two choices now:

1. Re-compile your python, with libreadline?-dev installed.
2. Install the standalone version of readline, using `pip install readline` or `easy_install readline`

Comment: 1. How can I recompile the python?
2. I have tried the methods you said, but they were not worked.
"Unknown or unsupported command 'install'" and "error: Not a recognized archive type: readline"

Comment: So where does your python 2.7.2 come from? From a PPA or somewhere else?

Comment: "sudo apt-get install python"

Comment: No, if your OS is exactly Ubuntu 10.04, this would install a Python 2.6.5 instead. While Ubuntu 11.10 ships with Python 2.7.2, are you having any trouble in your OS rather than Python?

Comment: You are right.I usually use windows OS,  I have to use Ubuntu this time because of my task.Thanks,I'll try what you said.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and I fixed it in this way, hope it will be helpful to you.

$ source Install_Python2.7.5.sh

Shell script "Install_Python2.7.5.sh" is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev

sudo aptitude install build-essential libreadline5-dev

sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev

if [ ! -d ~/software/Python/Python-2.7.5 ]; then

    mkdir ~/software
    mkdir ~/software/Python
    mkdir ~/software/Python/Python-2.7.5
fi

if [ ! -d ~/bin ]; then

    mkdir ~/bin
fi

user_root=~

echo $user_root

echo "unpackage Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2..."

tar -jxvf Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2 

echo "prepear to install Python-2.7.5"

cd Python-2.7.5

sed -i "s/#readline/readline/g" Modules/Setup.dist

echo "Start to install Python-2.7.5"

./configure --prefix=$user_root/software/Python/Python-2.7.5/  && make && make install

echo "Make symbol link"

ln -s -f $user_root/software/Python/Python-2.7.5/bin/* $user_root/bin

echo "Set environment variable"

PATH=$user_root/bin:$PATH
```